# Determine the groups of order $p^2q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, such that $p$ does not divide |Aut(G)|.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine the groups of order $p^2q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, such that $p$ does not divide |Aut(G)|.

**Hint - begin as follows:**

Let $P$ be a $p-$Sylow subgroup of $G$. Consider $P \rightarrow G$, where an element of $P$ acts via conjugation. **...**

*I am not sure where to go with this. I do know since $P$ acts by conjugation on $G$, we get a homomorphism from $P \rightarrow Aut(G)$, and since $p$ does not divide |Aut(G)|, the kernel of the homomorphism is P, which is in the center of $G$. Also, $P$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ since $P$ acts by conjugation on $G$.*

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989999/classify-groups-of-order-pq2-using-semidirect-product).

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I could still use more help, but will use this as a reference. I appreciate it!

Comment: Did you read the answer by Justin Benfield? You can follow this with your assumptions.

Comment: I am having difficulty with it, but will try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are none.  A p-Sylow must be central, hence also normal and unique, to avoid an inner automorphism of order p.  But then a q-Sylow is also central, normal, and unique, so G is abelian.  But then it is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, so every automorphism of its p-Sylow induces an automorphism of the same order on G (by acting trivially on the other direct factor).  But every group of order $p^2$ has an automorphism of order p.  (If cyclic, its automorphism group has order $p(p-1)$ and otherwise is has order $p(p-1)^2(p+1)$.)

Comment: So this means that there is no such group since any group of this sort would result in p dividing the order of Aut(G) correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Thank you for your help.